# Can't get jquery form validation to register $.post element

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, submit

I want to validate a form such that I can check the basics (such as username entered, username a minimum length, etc.) but also such that I can ensure things like username and email have not already been (which requires a database search).

I have all the pieces, and after playing around have narrowed it down to find that the `$.post` statement, while it is meant to add to my 'fail' counter, is not doing so.  How can I get some form of output from the `$.post` line so that I can truly validate (because right now, even if the username is not available, it will submit the form).

Here is my `<script>` (although for simplicity shortened to just show the username piece).  Note that 'usernameoff' is my error block:

```
function validateForm()
{
   // set variables
   var username=document.forms["registrationnew"]["username"].value;
   var usernamespace=username.indexOf(" ");

   // set fail counter variable to determine if any requirements failed
   var counter=0;

   // check that username isn't blank, containing spaces, too short, or taken
   if (username==null || username=="")
   {
      counter++;
      $('#usernameoff').html("Must enter a username");
   }
   else if (username.indexOf(" ") >= 0)
   {
      counter++;
      $('#usernameoff').html("Cannot contain spaces");
   }
   else if (username.length < 3)
   {
      counter++;
      $('#usernameoff').html("Must be at least three characters");
   }
   else
   {
      $.post("check_username.php", {username: username}, function(result)
      {
         if(result == 0)
         {
            $('#usernameoff').html("Available");
         }
         else
         {
            counter++;
            $('#usernameoff').html("Not available");
         }
      });
   }  

   // if any test failed, return false
   if (counter > 0)
   {
      document.getElementById("errorflag").innerHTML=counter;
      return false;
   }
}
```

`$.post` conducts a query to determine whether or not the username entered has already been taken (and returns 0 or 1).  My issue is that, regardless of which it returns, it does not increment 'counter', and therefore the form still submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final test (`if (counter > 0)`) will run before your AJAX call has returned. This is the 'asynchronous' part of AJAX.

The simplest solution, in your case, is to replace `$.post` with a synchronous call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "check_username.php", 
  data: {'username': username},
  async: false,
  success: function(result) { /* ... */ }
});
```

This will cause a delay while your script waits for the return, but since it's on your own server, that delay should be fairly minimal.

(Synchronous calls aren't always possible. Read the docs for [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more.)

Comment: Thank you SO much, this problem was killing me yesterday, and I just tried it out this way with success. I'm coding up my first ever website (took a 1 semester coding course and caught the bug), so this is all a big learning experience.  Thanks a ton again.